# Swift FileManager - no such file

Tags: swift, url, swift3, nsfilemanager

I am trying to upload videos. I get true for fileExists but in the logs I see -

> Body file is unreachable:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BE71B534-5051-4552-8491-30E1FE34E128/Documents/upload/306A4291-5E5A-467E-B2F7-8FFCA5BFFC1D1520419887-676644831.mp4
>
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
>   “306A4291-5E5A-467E-B2F7-8FFCA5BFFC1D1520419887-676644831.mp4”
>   couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

```
let dir = "/upload/"
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let path = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(dir)

    do {

        if let urlArray = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: path,
                                                                       includingPropertiesForKeys: [.contentModificationDateKey],
                                                                       options:.skipsHiddenFiles)  {

            let mp4Files = urlArray.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mp4" }

            for videoFile in urlArray {

                let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: videoFile.path)

                if fileExists {


                    let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: videoFile.path)

                    self.uploadVideo(url: url)
                }


            }
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

To save the video I use -

```
        let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl)

        if((urlData) != nil) {

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                urlData?.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)

            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

**create Directory using this code**

```
var nextItemDirUrl : URL!

func createDownloadSongDirIfNotForNextItem() {
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let logsPath = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("upload")
        nextItemDirUrl = logsPath

        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: logsPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            print("Directory created at:",logsPath)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
```

After save your file using `nextItemDirUrl` in `DocumentDirectory`

```
let destinationUrl = nextItemDirUrl.appendingPathComponent("yourView.mp4")
yourVideoData.write(to: destinationUrl, atomically: true)
```

Comment: what is dirUrl?

Comment: @Ros my mistake its `nextItemDirUrl`

Comment: Same issue..  :/

Comment: @Ros after storing file at path, have you checked that file actually stored or not?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by doing -

```
let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: videoFile)

    if((urlData) != nil) {

       let lastPath = "/videos/" + "temp.mp4"

       let path = documentDirectory.appending(lastPath)

       urlData?.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
       let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)
       self.uploadVideo(url: url)
}
```